# ¿para que sirve el punto (".") en java script?

Tags: javascript

Vi de forma reiterada que el punto se usaba en eventos, en variables, en dom, pero nunca supe cual era exactamente su funcion, ni su significado exacto. Me gustaria saber cual es su definicion, como se le llama a este "punto",  y cual es su funcion, gracias.
ej:

```
variable.textcontent
```

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar un ejemplo de uso de *el punto*?

Answer (score 1):

el punto sirve para acceder a propiedades y metodos de los objetos (propios y nativos de javascript) como por ejemplo:

```
document.querySelector(".elemento").appendChild(otroElemento)
```

el objeto Document tiene un metodo llamado querySelector que selecciona segun un string pasado por parametros algun elemento dentro del DOM. Como este metodo devuelve un HTML Element (que tambien es un objeto) podemos usar el metodo de los objetos HTML "appendChild" para agregar otro elemento como hijo.
Pero no solo se accede a metodos sino a propiedades por ejemplo si tenemos el objeto:

```
let objeto = { name : "nombre", surname : "apellido" }
```

accedemos a la propiedad surname escribiendo `objeto.surname`

Answer (score 1):

El punto se usa mayormente en lenguajes de programación orientada a objetos o con estructuras.

Imagina que tienes un objeto `persona`:

```js
let persona = {
    nombre: "Alan",
    edad: 20
}

console.log(persona.edad)
```

Si quisieras acceder o modificar su campo `edad` lo haces interponiendo el punto entre `persona` y `edad`. Así: `persona.edad`.

En lenguajes cómo Javascript, los objetos también pueden tener funciones (llamadas **métodos**). Por ejemplo, tomando el modificando anterior:

```js
let persona = {
    nombre: "Alan",
    edad: 20,
    saludar: function(){
        console.log("Hola, soy " + this.nombre)
    }
}

persona.saludar()
```